# OSX Mountain Lion logs out after login

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I open the lid of the laptop and the computer wakes up. I fill in my password and log in.  I'm shown the desktop for a second and then the screen goes black.  I then have to hit a key or two to wake it up again.  Then I'm force to log in once more.

Anyone seen this?  How can I fix it?

Comment: This happens to me too! I'd love to see an answer.

Comment: Do you have a "hot corner" set to lock screen? I've had this happen and I've always blamed the mouse being left in that corner, but I haven't figured out if that's actually true.

Comment: @KevinReid The hot corner settings appear to be all empty :(

Comment: @KevinReid It looks from your description that you cannot log in except momentarily, so how do you know the hot corner settings are empty?

Comment: @PhilipKearns I think you addressed the wrong person.

Comment: Sorry Kevin.  @HonzaPokorny, It looks from your description that you cannot log in except momentarily, so how do you know the hot corner settings are empty?

Comment: @PhilipKearns Well, when I log in the second time, I can then use the computer as usual...

Comment: Can you try it on a different user?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you dont have Log-In options enabled.  If they are, disable them.  It sounds like you might be running a Log-In option.

Check out this link to learn more about Log-In options.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10650?viewlocale=en_US

EDIT:
Since you don't have any log in options enabled, it sounds like it might just be a lag from the screen waking up.

Does this happen when you are attached to an external monitor as well?  Or does it only occur when you open the lid?

Comment: It looks like they are actually off. :(